# Evitar proceso mediante before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy desarrollando los permisos de usuario y estoy intentando usar un before_action para evaluar una condicional, si devuelve false quiero que la acción "create" no se ejecute, pero si devuelve true podrá crearse el registro

este seria mi before_action:

```
before_action :permiso_create, only: [:create]

def create
  @producto = Producto.new(producto_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @producto.save
      format.html { redirect_to @producto, notice: 'Producto was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @producto }
      format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'El producto se ha creado de forma exitosa.'} #ajax
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @producto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'Error al crear el producto.'} #ajax

    end
  end
end
```

si la condicional devuelve verdadero que no se crea el registro o no se ejecute la acción create mostrándose un flash alert con el mensaje de "permiso denegado"

he intentado con unprocessable_entity pero no me devuelve el mensaje, deteniendo el proceso antes de mostrarlo, de esta forma:

```
def permiso_create
  @puede_crear = current_usuario.profiles.find_by_Descripcion("products").Altas
  if @puede_crear != true
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {flash.now[:alert] = 'you don't have permission.'}
      end
     head :unprocessable_entity

  end
end
```

de que forma podría evitar el create y enviar ese mensaje? gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el *callback* detenga la ejecución de la acción, debes llamar `render` o `redirect_to`; en tu caso lo mejor sería utilizar `render`; por ejemplo:

```
def permiso_create
  @puede_crear = current_usuario.profiles.find_by_Descripcion("products").Altas

  unless @puede_crear
    flash.now[:alert] = 'you don't have permission.'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Notas:

- `!= true` no es necesario, simplemente puedes utilizar `!@puedes_cerar` para negar la evaluación, o mejor aún (y como lo muestro en el ejemplo), puedes utilizar `unless`.
- Utilicé la acción `new` asumiendo que el usuario viene de ahí, pero ajusta el código para que sea la vista correcta.
- Quité `format.js` (de hecho todo el bloque `respond_to`) ya que parece que buscas mostrar un mensaje `flash`, pero en caso que necesites utilizar `js`, simplemente puedes utilizar `render js: 'new'`, donde `new` corresponde a la vista *javascript* (e.g. `new.js.erb`) que deseas mostrar.